# java generate regular expression from localized NumberFormat

Tags: java, regex, number-formatting

Is there any clean way to generate a regular expression that will match values formatted with a locale-configured java NumberFormat?  Or some library that will do so?

This is in a web-based app & I want to pass the regex out to the jsp page for javascript validation on numeric fields.  Locale varies on a per-user basis & I'd like to not have to hand-code specific regexes for every number format out there.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `DecimalFormat` uses [its own pattern language](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

You can get the pattern string like this:

```
DecimalFormat nf = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
// ...
String patter = nf.toLocalizedPattern();
```

Which on my system returns `"¤#,##0.00"`

You might be able to roll your own function that converts that to a regex (limited to the cases that are used in your application), but it's not in the standard library and I'm not aware of any third-party library that does it.

Comment: So you're saying this is my chance for glory...

Thanks, this gets me part of way home.  I'll hold out hope for a bit that someone else may chime in with the remainder.